# How can I begin taking snapshots of an already running ElasticSearch cluster with no prior repository setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, devops

I've recently started working on ELK Stack in my organisation, and there's a requirement that has got me wondering.

The cluster details are as follows:

- Hosted on AWS EC2 instances
- No repository has been registered for backups
- A curator is up an running, but not yet being utilized
- Using instance store

During my research, I learnt that the best way to backup is by using the [Snapshot API method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/modules-snapshots.html), but the **problem** is that it requires **registering repositories**(such as S3), and a **node restart**.

I've been **told** that a **restart** will cause all the **data in that node to be lost**. Is this true? If not, what would be the best way to go around to begin automated backups without any loss of data, if it's possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't mention, if you use EBS or an instance store. In the day to day, its easy forget that a stop instance isn't a restart instance.
Be careful to use a disk storage of type instance store.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731496/lost-aws-ec2-disk-data-after-reboot

Comment: @JuanCarlosAlafita Oh! Thank you for that pointer. We are using instance store as of now. If you could throw a little more light, does an ElasticSearch 'node' restart mean an 'instance' restart?

Comment: No, as glenacota said previously ElasticSearch 'node' restart  mean only restart the ES application/process(like   "sudo service elasticsearch restart")
When I said 'instance restart' I meant EC2 instance restart.
For what you need to do(install a plugin), no reboot of the EC2 instance is required.
I put my comment, so that you take into account the type of store you use for your EC2 instance.
Node-> "Any time that you start an instance/process of Elasticsearch, you are starting a node"

Comment: So, talking about disk storage, the recommendation is always to use EBS volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restart the node to install the repository-s3 plugin (instructions here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/repository-s3.html). However, restarting a node doesn't mean destroying the EC2 instance with all the attached volumes. In other words, your data will outlive the node restart. Here [how to stop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/stopping-elasticsearch.html), here [how to start](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/starting-elasticsearch.html) again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Just to confirm, restarting a node will not have any effect on the data itself, but will only restart the ElasticSearch processes, right?

Comment: That's correct. You can check the `path.data` field of your `elasticsearch.yml` file to see where the data is currently persisted. Restarting a node won't delete the data directory. And once again, by restarting the node I mean restarting the Elasticsearch process on the current EC2 instance :)